# Check if any values of one column contains any values from another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

So I have a formula I've been using to see if any of the cells in one column matches any of the cells in another group of values (in a different sheet called companies):

```
 =IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(K1,companies!A:A,1,FALSE)),"Keep","Delete")
```

Now I'm trying to do the exact same thing, only now I want to see if any of the cells CONTAIN any substring of the cells (companies!A:A) rather than MATCH. Not sure how to do this though.

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE("*",K1,"*"),companies!A:A,1,FALSE)),"Keep","Delete")
```

Just change your `K1` reference to `CONCATENATE("*",K1,"*")`which will make the vlookup wildcard based.

[Here's an image showing this working, though modified to all be in one sheet.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogpLm.png) You can see one, four and five get delete because they're contained in the list, but not EXACTLY in the list.

**EDIT** So after some discussion in the comments, it turns out the above is a misunderstanding of the need.  The question actually wants to be able to see if a certain value contains ANY of the strings in another column, which is a bit more difficult of a problem - but this was bugging me so I worked on it and I think I've got something that works.

Here's the formula:

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*"&$H$2:$H$14&"*",I2))),"Delete","Keep")
```

**This has to be entered using CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER to make it an array function to work**

**The reference column must also be explicitly defined (i.e. H#:H#,not H:H) or else everything will return true, as the empty cells below your data will match anything.**

That all being said, you'll know its an array function because it will have brackets around the formula in the formula bar as you can see below.

[image: array formula]

I strongly recommend going through the "Evaluate Formula" tool to see how this works yourself, but I'll break it down best I can below, using an example of a matching row since it's more obvious.

First, excel evaluates your reference and concatenation into an array of the cell values and replaced your reference for the string to be searched, so we get something like:

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"*john*";"*jack*";"*fake*";"*bill*";"*bob*";"*test*";"*blah*";"*hey*";"*words*";"*ten*";"*eleven*";"*jim*";"*susie*"},"fake@example.org"))),"Delete","Keep")
```

Excel then performs the search for each of those terms against the string you want to search, and this returns an array of the results of that.  Note search returns "#VALUE" when there's no match.

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER({#VALUE;#VALUE;1;#VALUE;#VALUE;#VALUE;#VALUE;#VALUE;#VALUE;#VALUE;#VALUE;#VALUE;#VALUE})),"Delete","Keep")
```

Excel then does IsNumber against this array, and again, stores the True/False results in the array.

```
=IF(OR({FALSE;FALSE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE}),"Delete","Keep")
```

We then added the OR, which will evaluate against the array and return True if any of the results are True, and then the If is evaluated.

Seems to work, though performance may suck against a large dataset.  This kind of stuff would be better suited for some sort of SQL tool.

Comment: I have no idea why, I've checked and double checked and my formula matches (with my own corresponding columns), and it's returning "keep" for all. It does say that the formula "refers to empty cells" but when I trace the cell, it's not empty. When I copied your screenshot exactly, it works, so it seems like it's something up with my other sheet.

Comment: Thats very odd.  Is there anything you could share to help me look into that?  What version of excel are you using, what happens if you do "Evaluate Formula" from the Formulas tab?  I suspect you may be getting an error somewhere that is making iferror always true.

Comment: It almost seems like my wildcards aren't working, as it works correctly if it's an exact match. Here's a screenshot of when I trace precedents: http://i.imgur.com/hcdCT3G.jpg

Comment: I'm using 2011 Excel for Mac

Comment: So from that image, I think I misunderstood your query.  It looks like you want J2 to say "Delete" because it contains 'blah' which is listed in column H.  This is not what the formula I put performs, it looks up the value in I2 against all the values in H and will return "Delete" if anything contains it.  In this example, itll return delete if anything contains "blah@blah.com."  I'd have to think through the logic you want to figure it out and don't know if I can today.  I'd suggest editing your question with some sample data or images showing the type of lookup you want to prevent confusion.

Comment: Edited the post to add what I think should work, if not I give up!